# Is it possible to configure Thymeleaf with theme inheritance?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a project with templates arranged in theme folders. I would like the view resolver to try to find the template in the active theme directory first, and if not present, look in the parent theme directory. I realize this is possible by just configuring 2 resolvers and adjusting their prefixes and order. I would rather have this determined at runtime. The site operates as a news portal of sorts. And based on the category of the current post, a particular theme is activated, so the order of the view resolvers needs to change on each request.

[example template dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZMiE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) to switch between themes based on the request